# Which serialization format is this?

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, serialization, deserialization

I’m dealing with some serialized data fetched from an SQL Server database and that looks like this :

```
('|AFoo|BBaar|C61|DFoo&nbsp;Baar|E200060|F200523|G200240|', )
```

Any idea which format is this ? And is there any Python package that can deserilize this ?

Comment: A pipe delimited format?

Comment: How exactly did you get this data? (Why do you think it is "serialized"?) What do you think should be the result after processing this example input, and why?

Comment: This data comes from a single column in an MS SQL database table. I replaced some parts with foo/bar for the sake of anonymization. I'm sure it's a serialized array because the different fields represent different parts of a mailing address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you show is a tuple that contains one value - a string. You can use string.split to construct a list of the string's component parts - i.e., AFoo, BBaar etc

```
t = ('|AFoo|BBaar|C61|DFoo&nbsp;Baar|E200060|F200523|G200240|', )

for e in t:
    values = [v for v in e.split('|') if v]
    print(values)
```

**Output:**

```
['AFoo', 'BBaar', 'C61', 'DFoo&nbsp;Baar', 'E200060', 'F200523', 'G200240']
```

**Note:**

The *for* loop is used as a generic approach that allows for multiple strings in the tuple. For the data fragment shown in the question, this isn't actually necessary

Comment: Thank you. Actually, this is what I'm currently doing to extract the data (I also remove the capital letters at the beginning of each string) but I'm wondering if there isn't a python module that does this automatically.

Comment: I'm doing this: data_address = [
            row[1:] for row in
            string_address.split('|')[1:-1]
        ]